# CTParagraphStyleSetting + CoreText: Setting line spacing

Tags: ios, core-text, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to set the line spacing of `NSAttributedString`. The problem is that I can't set a small linespacing for the text. I can set huge values for the leading, like 25 or more, but small values are ignored. I'm trying to set `kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierMinimumLineHeight` or `kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierMinimumLineSpacing`, but it is not working.

This is my code, any help is appreciated.

```
CGFloat leading = 50.0;
CGFloat minMineHeight = 1;
CTTextAlignment alignment = kCTCenterTextAlignment;

const CTParagraphStyleSetting styleSettings[] = {

    {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierMinimumLineSpacing, sizeof(CGFloat), &minMineHeight},
    {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierMinimumLineHeight, sizeof(CGFloat), &minMineHeight},
    {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierLineSpacing, sizeof(CGFloat), &leading},
    {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierParagraphSpacing, sizeof(CGFloat), &leading},
    {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierAlignment, sizeof(CTTextAlignment), &alignment}
};

CTParagraphStyleRef style = CTParagraphStyleCreate((const CTParagraphStyleSetting*) &styleSettings, 5);
[mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName value:(__bridge id)style range:NSMakeRange(0, [mutableAttributedString length])];
CFRelease(style);

return mutableAttributedString;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to set the maximum line spacing.

Comment: Why? if what I want to do is narrow the size between lines.

Comment: yes, you are thinking of it wrong. CoreText determines the line height and then compares it to the minimum and maximum. You would use the minimum to *increase* the line spacing and the maximum to *decrease* it.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! that was the problem, thanks for the solution and for the explanation.